# thymeleaf set value for 'name' 'id' 'value' attr for input label

Tags: jsp, thymeleaf

I have a snippet in jsp file as following

```
<c:forEach var="question" items="${questionList }">
    <p>{{ question.question }}</p>

    <c:forEach var="answer" items="${question.answerList }">
        <input type="radio" name="${question.id }" id="${answer.id }" value="${answer.sequence }">
        <label for="${answer.id }">${answer.answer }</label>
    </c:forEach>

</c:forEach>
```

now I use thymeleaf template, I don't know how to implement it in thymeleaf. especially, I don't konw how to get `name` attr for `input`,

```
<div th:each="answer : ${question.answerList }">
    <input type="radio" name="how to do?" id="how to do?" value="how to do?" th:value="${answer.sequence}">
    <label th:text="${ans.answer}"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `th:with` for working with local variables in thymeleaf,

```
<div th:with="questionObj=${questionList}">
    <div th:each="answer: ${questionObj}">
        <input type="radio" th:name="${questionObj.id}" 
               th:id="${answer.id}" th:value="${answer.sequence}">
        <label th:text="${answer.answer}"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Refer: [Local Variables](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables)

Comment: thank you,  but now i have delete thymeleaf from my project and add jsp.